# How to 'install' and use in-house dependencies for other projects with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, build-system

**clarification**: If the below setup is a reasaonable way to do it, then my question is mainly, how do I best add the public headers with the .lib when I run *ninja install* as my solution does not do this currently.

There is a myriad of examples of how to do stuff in different ways, and many seem to contradict eachother to just confuse me even more.

I'm trying to change out a in-house build system and replace it with CMake. The codebase consists of many different components/libraries, like OS/Platform abstraction, networking, functionality etc. Before this was always compiled together as one big codebase, so running clean would remove everything and rebuild all dependencies.

Now it comes to the part where I have trouble understanding on how a modern smart way to do it in CMake is.

Ignoring the fact that a dependency-chain tool on top is needed, my idea was to build the components/libraries in order of libraries with no dependency to the topmost as isolated build runs.
Then each isolated build run would be built with its dependencies, like only the windows API for the OS abstraction library, and then run install and export on it.

- Is this the general prefered way, to compile a library to a .lib on windows or .a on linux and export it to a known shared location?
- Im guessing it would be required then to copy all public header files for this library to the same location? If so, how is this most correctly done?

If I have my OS abstraction folder structure

```
OSabstraction/
  includes/
    OSabstraction/
        abstraction.h
  src/
    abstraction.cpp
  CMakeLists.txt
```

and my CMakeLists is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(OSabstraction LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(abstraction)

target_sources(abstraction
    PRIVATE
        src/abstraction.cpp
)
target_include_directories(abstraction
    PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes/>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

install(
    TARGETS abstraction
    EXPORT abstraction-export
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
)
```

How would I best go around to use this library in many other inhouse projects? This library is in practice many times larger, so what would be the correct way to do it for a large project?

edit: I tried to follow [Pablo Arias' guide on how to do CMake Right](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/), but I am not sure how the build_interface and install_interface generators work in regards to getting my header files with the export of the .lib file.

Comment: The question is a little broad. As you have it, you will be able to build and install your OSAbstraction to any common location. You do this by setting the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX variable on the command line when invoking CMAKE. Other scripts can then be directed to use this path as a library/include search path by setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. Your pre-built libraries can then be found by `find_package()`.

Comment: Yes I am aware, the problem is that, in my ignorance, is that it seems that it is many ways to complete this goal, and as I wrote, many answers seem to contradict each other. Also the above solution is not working for me. Again, I am not sure how to as correctly as possible export .lib and its headers with the given example. Or if there are better ways to do it. If that cleared it up some?

Comment: I think it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Are you looking to build a multi-library, multi-platform SDK which others in your organisation can use, or are you looking to simply include one OSabstraction library into each other executable you build? If the former, probably a cmake of cmakes which builds the SDK. If the latter, you can either have the abstraction as a git submodule of your executables or use externalproject_add to build it into the build directory of each solution.

Comment: I don't know if this would answer your question but here is how I'd do it. Create a CMakeLists.txt for each "part" that should be library. In that txt file expose the headers to any project that calls on this CMakeLists.txt. On you main project you would just need to add_library each subproject and it will build and add its headers to the build system. The final product would be the executable for you.

Comment: **Too broad** as you have too many questions/problems in the question post. If you just want to ask about properly exporting of the project you show us, then concentrate only on that project and show the error message you got. From what I immediately see, you forget to install header files, "abstraction-export" file and the "Config" file itself (which should include installed "abstraction-export" file).

Comment: @RichardHodges: For the purposes of this question the latter is more what I am looking for. The former is something I can piece together later when I get this subject under control. So you mean I should rather include it directly with externalproject instead of running install on the libraries induvidually, and exporting its .lib and header files to a common location?

Comment: @Tsyvarev : Its the whole point. I am not asking for nitty gritty details, I am asking about the broad term. Is installing local dependencies to a common location by its .lib file and headers, and then including them a good way to do it. If so, how do I include the public headers.

Comment: I feel your pain. The documentation of cmake sucks and everyone has their own view of "best practice". I could sit and write a tutorial for you, but it would take me a while. At this point I am tempted to say that I am for hire as a consultant... :)

Comment: @poipoikuroi: Note, that Stack Overflow is NOT a discussion forum. While we may ask additional details in the comments, at some point we want to see a **clear problem statement** in the **question post**, so we can answer it. Currently I am unable to see the problem statement in your question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev :  Isnt my clarification on top pretty clear? as RichardHodges said, its many "best practices" and many ways you should not do it, so its impossible from where I stand to ask something very specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended solution is to use a package manager together with CMake.
The link below is a full C++ project setup template which can use the package manager https://conan.io/ to support splitting up dependencies into individual libraries.

https://github.com/trondhe/cmake_template